# Jitter in hover transformation CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

When I use a CSS transformY in a hover property, when the user mouses over the top part of the navigation element, it jitters because the box moved down as it detects a hover and therefore moves out the way of the cursor, which then causes the hover property to be removed, thus the transform gets removed. I would like some help so this jitter doesn't happen, but still accomplished the individual tab move. I am using a combination of bootstrap and my own code to accomplish this.

You can see demo here of what I mean:

https://jsfiddle.net/b5vjw9wk/1/

html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-full navbar-default navbar-bottom navbar-drop-shadow">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-flex-nav">
      <div class="col-flex-3 center active-nav" id="NewHires">
        <h4>Active Nav</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-flex-3 center non-active-nav" id="Transfers">
        <h4>Non Active</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-flex-3 center non-active-nav" id="Leaving">
        <h4>Non Active</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
  background-color: rgb(110,14,24);
  border: 0px;
}
.navbar-drop-shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
          box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
.non-active-nav {
  color: white;
  -webkit-transition: transform .06s; /* Safari */
  transition: transform .06s;
}
.non-active-nav:hover {
  background: rgb(110,14,24);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 4px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 4px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
          box-shadow: 0 6px 4px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  transform: translateY(10px);
  border-radius: 3px;
}
html, body {
  background: rgb(75,75,75);
}
.active-nav{
  color: white;
  background: rgb(75,75,75);
  -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 7px 9px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 7px 9px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow:         inset 0 7px 9px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  transform: translateY(10px);
}
.navbar-bottom {
  min-height: 25px;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.no-margin{
  margin: 0px;
}

.row-flex-nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col-flex-3 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You could increase the size of the element (pushing it downwards) instead of translating it. That way your mouse continues to hover through the animation.

Comment: I have attempted that, but the entire row gets larger when I do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One technique I've used before is to add a transparent border and negative margin to the top of the element so that it's impossible to hover off the element as it transitions.

```
.non-active-nav {
    color: white;
    -webkit-transition: transform .06s; /* Safari */
    transition: transform .06s;

    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    margin-top: -10px; /* equal to border width */
}
```

Example:

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css");

.navbar {
 background-color: rgb(110,14,24);
 border: 0px;
}
.navbar-drop-shadow {
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
   box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
.non-active-nav {
 color: white;
 -webkit-transition: transform .06s; /* Safari */
    transition: transform .06s;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
.non-active-nav:hover {
 background: rgb(110,14,24);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 4px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 4px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
   box-shadow: 0 6px 4px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 transform: translateY(10px);
 border-radius: 3px;
}
html, body {
 background: rgb(75,75,75);
}
.active-nav{
 color: white;
 background: rgb(75,75,75);
 -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 7px 9px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 7px 9px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow:         inset 0 7px 9px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    transform: translateY(10px);
}
.navbar-bottom {
 min-height: 25px;
}
.center {
 text-align: center;
}

.no-margin{
 margin: 0px;
}

.row-flex-nav {
 width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col-flex-3 {
 flex-grow: 1;
 width: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-full navbar-default navbar-bottom navbar-drop-shadow">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-flex-nav">
      <div class="col-flex-3 center active-nav" id="NewHires">
        <h4>Active Nav</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-flex-3 center non-active-nav" id="Transfers">
        <h4>Non Active</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-flex-3 center non-active-nav" id="Leaving">
        <h4>Non Active</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b5vjw9wk/2/)